# Display all categories with specific attributes in magento

Tags: magento, attributes, categories

I've been looking for several hours but I don't think anyone has said much about this.

I have created a drop-down category attribute. I would like to display all the categories for one on the values in the drop-down. Actually I want to display all the values but separately, that way I can create four columns of category listings.

I can display the attribute on the category page but i need to be able to echo the list on all the pages.

I haven't really come to close as I'm not to good at Php at all.

Here's what I have so far:

```
 <?php if($_category->getMajorHeading()): ?> 
       <?php echo  $_category->getUrl(); ?>

 <?php endif; ?>
```

I tried foreach but no luck with that. I followed one tutorial and I can get all the categories to  print out but I need them in four separate rows not a long list. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You should use category collection and apply filter.

http://www.magentocommerce.com/knowledge-base/entry/magento-for-dev-part-8-varien-data-collections

Comment: Thank you. I've put this project off for a little while but I'm sure I will get back to it and this link seems like just what I need.